# Parsing Malformed HTML with PHP Dom

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument

I've got a client who wants their videos (provided by a third party) displayed on their web site. The web site uses swfobject to display the video, so I thought that it would be easiest to grab that and slightly modify it so that it works on the client's web site.

Using PHP DOMDocument seems the way to go, but unfortunately the HTML that is provided is malformed and causes a heart attack. Is it possible to get it to ignore the errors in the HTML, or an alternative way that I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [PHP Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) is for. For [example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php):

> ```
> <?php
> ob_start();
> ?>
> <html>a html document</html>
> <?php
> $html = ob_get_clean();
>
> // Specify configuration
> $config = array(
>            'indent'         => true,
>            'output-xhtml'   => true,
>            'wrap'           => 200);
>
> // Tidy
> $tidy = new tidy;
> $tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
> $tidy->cleanRepair();
>
> // Output
> echo $tidy;
> ?>
> ```

See [HTML Tidy Configuration Options](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you like jQuery, you can use "[Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)". It works great.